# sending json data from django-view to ajax

Tags: json, ajax, django, django-views

I am trying to transfer json data from django view to template by using ajax.
**Here** is my `ajax code`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("this is getting executed")
    $.ajax({
           url: "/get_ecommdata/",
           type: "get",
           cache: "false",
           dataType : 'json',
           success: function(data) {
              console.log("This is working fine")
              alert(data)
           },
           error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              console.log("this is error")
                alert(xhr.status)
           },
  })
});
```

**View is as below:**

```
def get_ecommdata(request):
    print "inside get_ecommdata"
    tempdata = ['{"square": 0, "key": 0}', '{"square": 1, "key": 1}', '{"square": 4, "key": 2}']
    return HttpResponse(tempdata)
```

status code is **200** but still "this is error" is displayed on console i.e. its executing error part.

**Here is what I understand:**

status code is 200 i.e. server is sending data properly but there is some issue identifying the datatype.
This code is working fine for simple text but not for json.

**My Question**

Can someone give me some directions about passing json data from django-view to ajax. I think I am making some stupid mistake here.

P.S. I have gone through other posts which are similar (json,ajax,view) but none of them caters to this  specific question.

Comment: Use JsonResponse: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: Does not seem to be a valid json to me.You should wrap it up in [ ], plus no single quotes around them, Look at my answer below if it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import the json module

```
import json
```

Then Try this in your request method

```
data = json.dumps([{"square": 0, "key": 0}, {"square": 1, "key": 1}, {"square": 4, "key": 2}])    

return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

**NOTE**

Using single quotes as in your snippet would result in the following output

```
'["{\\"square\\": 0, \\"key\\": 0}", "{\\"square\\": 1, \\"key\\": 1}", "{\\"square\\": 4, \\"key\\": 2}"]'
```

Its confusing for a seeker , hence i used the above method. But it depends on choice.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Using json.dumps did solved my problem.
For the record. issue was in django-view. Here is updated code that is working fine.
`def get_ecommdata(request):
    print "inside get_ecommdata"
    tempdata = ['{"square": 0, "key": 0}', '{"square": 1, "key": 1}', '{"square": 4, "key": 2}']
    # tempdata = "hello"
    tempdata1 = json.dumps(tempdata)
    return HttpResponse(tempdata1,content_type="application/json")`

Comment: Superb :-), but i would still suggest to avoid using quotes as it would result in unnecessary \\ in your result. You can see the result of json.dumps in your case it would contain double slashes which is confusing. But if you are ok with it then good :-) but as an answer i think we should let them know about it. What say ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_ecommdata(request):
    print "inside get_ecommdata"
    list_square = [
        {"square": 0, "key": 0},
        {"square": 1, "key": 1},
        {"square": 4, "key": 2}
    ]
    data = json.dumps(list_square)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```